# how to share homestead laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, homestead, configuration-management

I'm new to Laravel and I'm not sure how to share the project on github.

My site works fine locally using Homestead. I committed it to github and downloaded it on another computer. I then realized that the vendor folder is not included and that I didn't have php installed on the other computer.

My question is, how do you do configuration management in homestead? Is there a way to automatically install the dependencies and simply use vagrant up to see the website in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to install and run `composer` on the new machine. `composer update` will download all your project's dependencies. All you need is to have `composer.json` in your project folder.

Alternatively you can remove `/vendor` folder from `.gitignore` file so Git could commit and checkout this folder too, but it's a bad practice.

Comment: actually used `composer install` but yeah that worked. thanks